# Java difference between || and && in this example

Tags: java

I am making a counter between number ranges and not sure the correct way to do this. I have always used the `||` operator but reading some examples, I feel I should be using the `&&` command. Here is my example problem...

```
if(value >= 1 || value <=10){
    count1++;
}
else if(value >= 11 || value <= 20){
    count2++;
// AND SO ON........
```

Or should I be using the `&&` operator like

```
if(value >= 1 && value <= 10){
    count1++;
}
else if value >= 11 && value <= 20){
    count2++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`||` means "[or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)".
`&&` means "[and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)".

`value >= 1 || value <= 10` makes no sense because it's always true. All numbers are 1 or more, or 10 or less. Some numbers are both, but that doesn't matter.

`value >= 1 && value <= 10` makes far more sense. There's a limited range of numbers (`[1..10]`) for which both the first condition and the second condition are true.

Answer (score 0):

`||` is the or operator, so the condition `value >= 1 || value <=10` is true for all values if you think about it. So, unless you want your counts to be meaningless, use `&&` which is the and operator.